# Help translating English idioms

Tags: translation, word-choice, nuances, word-usage

Can someone use 涙ぐむ in a way to say "could bring a man to tears" or something along those lines?

Wanting to translate some English phrases or sayings into Japanese in a way that could be either literal or natural.

Comment: I doubt that the literal translation would have nearly the same meaning as it does in English.  You might be better off looking for equivalent Japanese idioms.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone use 涙ぐむ in a way to say "could bring a man to tears" or something along those lines?

Certainly. It could be done by turning 「涙ぐむ」 into its causative form 「涙ぐませる」.  You could say:

> 「[Something] は（その）人を涙ぐませるかもしれない。」

That is natural-sounding.

An even more natural way to say this, however, would be to use a person as the grammatical subject and use the verb 「涙ぐむ」 as is without using the causative form.  You can say, for instance:

> 「[Person(s)] はそれを聞いて/見て涙ぐむかもしれない。」